# How to program Button to add DataGrid row with values?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, submit

My program has an email field, a password field, and a DataGridView to the right. There is a submit button as well. The submit button edits the preset row in the DataGridView but if clicked twice will just re-edit the contents of the first row.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = txtEmail.Text;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = txtPass.Text;
```

I'm wondering how I can program the button to add a NEW row with the value of `txtEmail` and `txtPass`. Is there a set method to adding rows via button? And once that is done how would I edit the most recently added row? This will present a new row with the new email and new pass every time data is submitted?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Preferably somebody who is very experienced in C# please, thanks.

Comment: Hilarious how people can edit my post but can't answer a question that they reformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `DataGridView` has only two columns, and that it's `DataSource` property is not bound to some collection or a `DataTable`, this should work:

```
private void btnAddInputToGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add the new row, get its index
    var newIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtEmail.Text, txtPass.Text);

    // select just the new row
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.Rows[newIndex].Selected = true;

    // select the cell you're interested in and put it in edit mode
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[newIndex].Cells[0];
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
}
```

Comment: ThankYou Grant, this was very helpful and did the trick. However, my DataGrid starts with 1 Blank Row? So when I use your code the first account to be added to the list goes underneath that? How can I remove this default row? Thanks again